# TypeError: done is not a function query callback

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, node-sqlserver

I am trying to save a result of a query into a variable, I have read that you have to use a callback to do this. I am having problems with this process and receiving an error.

```
function getQryUser(user) {
  if (user.chkUserStatus) {
    var qryUser = request.query("SELECT someItems on someTbls", function(err, rows, done) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err, null);
      } else {
        return done(null, rows[0]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and from where I am calling my function

```
var qryUser = getQryUser(user);
```

Comment: TypeError: done is not a function

Comment: Pro-tip: Get into the habit of formatting your code correctly. It will help you and everyone else identify issues faster. I just formatted it for you so you can get an idea of what it should look like :) As for your problem, have you tried doing `console.log(done)` to see what `done` actually is? Does the documentation state that you should get a `done` callback here? Based on [this](https://github.com/Azure/node-sqlserver/blob/master/test/query.js) you should not be getting a `done` function. Just a possible error and the results.

Comment: If you're interested in getting the results from the query back from the function, you may want to check out [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using [node-sqlserver](https://github.com/Azure/node-sqlserver), `query()` callback takes only two parameters, `error` and `results`. Here's an example from their official [unit tests](https://github.com/Azure/node-sqlserver/blob/master/test/query.js):

```
sql.query(conn_str, "SELECT 1 as X, 'ABC', 0x0123456789abcdef ", function (err, results) {
    assert.ifError(err);

    var buffer = new Buffer('0123456789abcdef', 'hex');
    var expected = [{ 'X': 1, 'Column1': 'ABC', 'Column2': buffer}];

    assert.deepEqual(results, expected, "Results don't match");
    ...
```

Did you perhaps look at the [unit tests](https://github.com/Azure/node-sqlserver/blob/master/test/query.js) for examples yourself and picked up `done()` from there? Note that it comes from the parent `suite()` scope outside of `query()` and is thus not relevant in general `query()` API usage.